# Firebase crash reporting for iOS doesn't send crashes despite successful init

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I added firebase crash reporting to my iOS project (added pod, added build phase script, added json to project, ...).
When i run my app, i see in my console:

```
Firebase Crash Reporting: Successfully enabled
```

For testing, i insert fatalError() in my code after my FIRApp.configure() code (as suggested here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#create_your_first_error).

No crash reports are sent at my next app launch (that doesn't crash). I see nothing in my xcode console and nothing in my web console.

Comment: Does the app crash right away on startup? If so, that doesn't work as the SDK needs time to send the crash.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not an immediate solution, but some diagnostic tricks that may help locate the problem:

- Make sure that the debugger is **DISABLED** when you generate the crash in the simulator or attached device, or the debugger will grab the crash before FCR does. Launch the app (⌘R) in Xcode, stop the debugger (⌘.) in Xcode, and re-launch the app manually in the simulator or on the device.
- If you are using the simulator and you follow the above instructions, then you should see the raw crash dumps produced if you execute the command `find ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator -path '*/FCRDumps/*.dmp' -ls` (note that unprocessed crashes from other test apps will also be displayed).
- If you see one or more dump files with the right timestamp, then you should get a successful upload the next time the app launches. Remove the `fatalError()` line, then rebuild and relaunch. The `.dmp` files in that container should soon disappear, replaced by `.crash` files (use `find ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator -path '*/FCRCrashQueue/*.crash' -ls` to find them). The crash files will be deleted one at a time after they successfully upload.

Comment: The crash report works fine when debug mode. When I distribute to TestFlight and the app crashes, no data is generated. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I found 6 `.dmp` files but no `.crash` files. I have my app running in the simulator and its not attached to the debugger. I ran it with fatalError() and without fatalError() I got the `Firebase Crash Reporting: Successfully enabled ` but no reports in my Firebase Console :(

Comment: I'm using Xcode 8.1, it's not working on the simulator at all, but on a real device it works just fine. Maybe just give it a try on one.

Comment: it worked in simulator too.First i execute using .fataError() line in my code then app crashes ,then checked crash reports but not found.I checked using the above command in terminal then it show list of bugs. Then i remove .fatalError line from code and run the project then it shows "Crashes uploaded successfully:"  in console. then when i checked the reports it is showing the error

Comment: Important note: You have to generate the CRASH manually. The upload to Firebase itself can be done with debugger attached. So first fire off the crash from the debugger, then with "FatalError()" still in code, run the app manually. Then remove "FatalError()" and run the app from Xcode again.