# Firebase IOS Crash reporting not working - even when I force a crash

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm using Firebase Crash Reporting for IOS without cocoapods (manual install via SDK).

Crashes form my IOS app are not showing in the app dashboard, even when I force a crash. For example assert(false).

I'm using Firebase SDK https://dl.google.com/firebase/sdk/ios/3_2_1/Firebase.zip and this is what I've installed in my code

### Analytics

- FirebaseAnalytics.framework
- FirebaseInstanceID.framework
- GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework
- GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework
- GoogleUtilities.framework

### Crash (~> Analytics)

- FirebaseCrash.framework

**Can someone please confirm correct setup options, including settings in the GoogleService-Info.plist?**

Comment: See the accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748049/firebase-crash-reporting-for-ios-doesnt-send-crashes-despite-successful-init

Comment: Tks. So no relevant comments regarding GoogleService-info.plist?

Comment: There shouldn't need to be any changes to the one downloaded from the project settings.